# Creating a Ruby gem that talks to another gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, file-structure

I am working on creating an interface gem that works with the [Jira-Ruby gem](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby).

I have several questions and would like a general review for both my code and my attempt at creating a gem (I've never written one before). Any advice on where to go next would also be appreciated.

File structure:

```
jira_interface
   lib
      jira_interface
          config.rb
          version.rb
          app_interface.rb 
      jira_interface.rb
   jira_interface.gemspec
   #...etc files, I used bundle's gem command to set up
```

My main module (jira_interface.rb) looks like this:

```
require "jira_interface/version"
require "jira"
require "jira_interface/config"
require "jira_interface/app_interface"

module JiraInterface

  def get_jira_client
      @client = Jira::Client.new(USERINFORMATION)
  end

  def get_project(project_name)
     @client.Project.find(project_name)
  end

end
```

And my app_interface.rb looks like this:

```
class AppInterface < JiraInterface
  before_filter :get_jira_client

  def create_issue(issue_desc, project)
    issue = @client.Issue.build
    issue.save({"fields"=>{"summary"=> issue_desc, "project"=> {"id" => project.id}, "issuetype"=> {"id"=> "1"}}})
  end

  def update_issue(issue_id)
    issue = @client.Issue.find(issue_id)

    comment = issue.comments.build
    comment.save({"body"=> "This happened again at #{Date.time}"})
  end

  def get_issues(issue_desc, project_name)
    project = get_project(project_name)

    if project.issues.detect { |issue| issue.fields['summary'].include?(issue_desc) }
      update_issue(issue.id)
    else
      create_issue(issue_desc, project)
    end
  end

end
```

The goal is pretty simple: call `get_issues()` from the rails app when an error happens. If the error is already documented, post a comment saying that it happened again. If it's not, then create a new issue.

To the best of my knowledge, this should work because I've been following the examples found online.  However, I've been having a heck of a time just testing it. If anyone could suggest a good way of testing this, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Aside from what I posted in my answer, your approach looks great. Naming could be improved, but like they say, it is hard.

Keep the good work up!

Comment: does my answer help at all? If not, I'd very much appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a close look at **[how the gem you are using is tested](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/tree/master/spec)**. Those tests include **mocks** for all responses of the API (I assume) and is a good example for testing gems in general.

Notice:

- **helper methods** in the support folder including shared examples
- **mock data to simulate responses** from the source API
- **custom matchers** to make code better readable and reduce repetition of code (DRY-principle)

Those to me are the three most important you should embrace for now.